# Filter out if query returns nothing

Tags: python, sql

How can I filter out the results that I get back from the database so that I only can store the data which actually returns something.

I got the following code:

```
mergedlist_uniques = [id1,id2,id3,id4,..] #list containing data

for i in range(0, 5):
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM `id_activities` WHERE `id_activities`.`id` = '" + mergedlist_uniques[i] + "' LIMIT 1")
    results = cur.fetchall()
    if results != "":
        print("empty, result is: ", results)
        #data.append(results)
```

In my if statement I check whether the results contains nothing but this is not working.

I still get the following result:

```
>>> ('empty, result is: ', ())
```

what I should expect is that whenever the result is: () it should not print anything but if it contains:

```
>>> ('empty, result is: ', (idx))
```

then it should print out the result.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: be carefull when using the word result when working with query, a query will always return a result, some results are just nothing

Comment: ah thanks for the tip! I will modify it! @JeremyC.

Comment: I don't really understand 100% what your query is doing but what I seem to get is that you are doing your query for id = id1 to id5? and you want to print something like "empty result = (id5)" in case your query returns nothing for id5 right? nvm you already got the answer :p

Answer (score 3):

As per Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), `None, 0, "", (), {}, []` are treated as `False`, so use

```
if results:
    #DO something
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `filter` will solve your problem.

```
mergedlist_uniques = filter(None, [id1,id2,id3,id4,..])
```

This is an example of how `filter` works:

```
v = filter(None, ["foo", "", "bar"])
```

After the `filter`:

```
v = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get all you want with one SQL-query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM `id_activities` WHERE `id_activities`.`id`"
            " in ({})".format(",".join(mergedlist_uniques))
```